# How to integrate ckeditor to spree admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, spree

I am new to spree and ckeditor integration.

I want to integrate ckeditor to the spree admin. I could configure ckeditor correctly with rails_admin section of my website (following the steps in https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor), but now i want to add it to a field in the product edition page in the spree admin

The field is:

```
  <div data-hook="admin_product_form_description">
    <%= f.field_container :description, class: ['form-group'] do %>
      <%= f.label :description, Spree.t(:description) %>
      <%= f.text_area :description, { rows: "#{unless @product.has_variants? then '20' else '13' end}", class: 'form-control' } %>
      <%= f.error_message_on :description %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

I changed `f.text_area` to `f.cktext_area` but it didn't work...

Do you have any experience with this matter ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the trick.

You have to load the ckeditor javascript for the spree admin views.

For that add to spree_backend-3.0.0/app/views/spree/admin/shared/_head.html.erb (Via Deface or Override) the following line.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

And then simply you change your text area form `f.text_area` to `f.cktext_area`

Obviously, you have to follow before the steps to integrate ckeditor to your project. (https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor)